# Which method is more efficient String.equals(String s) or String.contains(String s)

Tags: java

For example, if I have a the following:

```
String s = "Alexander";
```

which is more efficient in this case, checking:

```
if(s.contains("Alexander"))
return true;
```

OR

```
if(s.equals("Alexander"))
return true;
```

Please note that this is just a basic example, all I need to know is understanding the root of method..Which is more efficient or faster?

Comment: They do different things, so I can't imagine why you'd ever need to pick between them on the basis of *efficiency* rather than *correctness*.

Comment: no research whatsoever...

Answer (score 7):

Just for the notes ;-)

```
String string = "Alex";
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int n = 0; n < 100000000; n++) if (string.contains("Alexander")) ;
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() -now));

now = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int  n = 0; n < 100000000; n++) if (string.equals("Alexander")) ;
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() -now));
```

Result:

```
Time: 1720
Time: 756
```

Comment: Changing `"Alex"` to `"Alexander Tales"`, the result is even clearer `Time: 3416` vs `Time: 764` :p

Answer (score 3):

this:

```
return s.equals("Alexander");
```

Answer (score 1):

`equals` is faster because it only needs to compare the strings starting from the beginning of both strings, whereas `contains` must loop over `s` to check whether `"Alexander"` begins and ends anywhere within `s`.

But ignoring that...

```
if (s.equals("Alexander"))
```

will be more efficient, because otherwise you have to do

```
if (s.contains("Alexander") && "Alexander".contains(s))
```

to guarantee equality.

Answer (score 1):

**Equals** is more efficient, it will only check if the strings match.
**Contains** will search the for that text inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code of the java String.java, you can realize that `Equals` is more efficient than `Contains`, since the first one checks first the size of the strings and then compares one by one each character. On the other hand, `Contains` calls the method `indexOf`, which searchs for an specific coincidence between the strings.

The purpose of both methods are completely different. You should use `equals` to test the equality between strings.

Answer (score 1):

They're two different methods so I'm not sure comparing them would be very realistic. However, as has been noted, `contains()` does the extra step of actually *searching* the string for the target value, whereas `equals()` simply checks whether the two strings are the same.